# How to use Android's LogCat within a Java project?

Tags: java, android, logcat, android-logcat

I have a Java Project, where i would like to use Android LogCat's debug-tagging functionality.

Is it somehow possible for Java projects? (not Android, but pure Java)

**EDIT:**

As stated below, it is not possible.
Is there any alternative for Java?

Comment: What about standart logging framerworks? ( log4j , slf4j, commons-logging ,  vanilla javaq logging... )

Comment: I would like to group my log-output by themes. Each group should be displayed separately, as LogCat does, by displaying them in separate tabs. As far as i know - none of standard frameworks can this.

Comment: you need just log framework in your application (there is a ton of them) and almost every one of them is configurable  so you can influence where log message goes.  It seems that you mix up your application and IDE where you are developing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Logcat is formatting the output of the ADB (the Android Debug Bridge). Since you can't connect the ADB to plain java projects, there is no way for you to use Logcat in such a fashion.

Unless ofcourse you get the Android Eclipse plugin's source code and modify it to your needs.

Comment: Thnx. Do you know an alternative for pure Java?

Comment: Unfortunately no, but if you search the Eclipse marketplace you just might find something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to use is something like [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j) or [tinylog](http://www.tinylog.org/)

Comment: Nope. It's not about the log framework that generates log, but about the tool to interactively watch those logs during development.